# libeoffice conected to oracle registeroutparameter to return resultset

Tags: oracle, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-base

Good Morning,

I have the following code:

```
Dim oraCon As Object

Sub Main
    openOracle("DB_LOC")    
    stmt  = oraCon.prepareCall("VARIABLE x REFCURSOR DECLARE V_Sqlstatement Varchar2(2000); BEGIN V_Sqlstatement:= 'SELECT * FROM DUAL'; OPEN x for v_Sqlstatement; ?:=x End;")
REM Whate do i put here?
    stmt.registerOutParameter(1, ????,????)
    rs=stmt.executeQuery()
End Sub
```

I am trying to find out what I should put in the registerOutParameter

Comment: Are you sure that SQL statement is correct? Because you have two statements: the `VARIABLE` declaration, which is not an SQL statement but a command used with the SQL\*Plus (and similar) client applications so is probably not going to be recognised by the database (because it is a client command, not an SQL statement); and then the second statement is the PL/SQL block `DECLARE ... BEGIN ... END;`. Oracle only allows a single statements per command. It should probably simply be `BEGIN OPEN ? FOR SELECT * FROM DUAL; End;` or maybe just `SELECT * FROM DUAL`.

Comment: The goal is to be able to get the cursor from the anonymous block. It is a variation of another code which works: stmt=oraCon.prepareStatement("DECLARE DAID INTEGER; CUR1 sys_refcursor; BEGIN INSERT INTO TABLE1(NAME) VALUES(?) RETURNING ID INTO DAID; OPEN CUR1 FOR SELECT DAID  FROM DUAL; dbms_sql.return_result(CUR1); END;")
 stmt.setString(1, "SAMPLE NAME")
 rs = stmt.executeQuery()
 rs.next
 print rs.getInt(1)
 rs.Close //and I cab successfully get the cursor back as resutset

Comment: My point was that the call you are making will not work because you are passing two statements in one command (which isn't allowed) and one of those statements is not actually an SQL statement (so is going to be invalid syntax). Yes, you can work out how to register the out parameter but when you do you'll find that the database will return syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call expects [XOutParameters](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1sdbc_1_1XOutParameters.html), where the 2nd parameter is a [DataType](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/namespacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1sdbc_1_1DataType.html) constant.

A complete example is given by user rodolfo at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41149.

```
sFormat = "minor"
oStmt = oConnection.prepareCall("CALL test_proc(?,?,?)")
' Input parameter binding is exactly the same as for prepared statements '
oStmt.setString(1, sFormat)

' Parameter 2, because it is the position of the question mark that is relevant. '
' For counting of the position all parameters (in, out) are equal '
oStmt.registerOutParameter(2, com.sun.star.sdbc.DataType.VARCHAR, "ignored")

' The final scale parameter says that we expect 2 digits after the decimal separator '
oStmt.registerNumericOutParameter(3, com.sun.star.sdbc.DataType.DECIMAL, 2)

oStmt.execute()
' NOTE: The .getXXX() methods are methods of the statement object and not of '
'       the result set! '
MsgBox "Mode: " & sFormat & " -- Version: " & oStmt.getString(2) _
      & chr(10) & "Numerical: " & oStmt.getString(3)

oStmt.close()
```

**EDIT**:

Multiple results are explained at https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1sdbc_1_1XStatement.html#ace0d6b1f30106a88de49a775ab275436:

> execute()
> boolean execute (   [in] string     sql )
> raises  (   SQLException
> )
> executes a SQL statement that may return multiple results.

> Under some (uncommon) situations a single SQL statement may return multiple result sets and/or update counts. Normally you can ignore this unless you are (1) executing a stored procedure that you know may return multiple results or (2) you are dynamically executing an unknown SQL string. The navigation through multiple results is covered by com::sun::star::sdbc::XMultipleResults.

> The execute method executes a SQL statement and indicates the form of the first result. You can then use com::sun::star::sdbc::XMultipleResults::getResultSet() or com::sun::star::sdbc::XMultipleResults::getUpdateCount() to retrieve the result, and com::sun::star::sdbc::XMultipleResults::getMoreResults() to move to any subsequent result(s).

> Parameters
> sql any SQL statement
> Returns
> TRUE if the next result is a ResultSet; FALSE if it is an update count or there are no more results
> Exceptions
> SQLException    if a database access error occurs.

Comment: So how would I register the parameter if the output is a cursor? I understand the call when it is a string or numeric, but I am still not yet clear if the output is a cursor. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @ZTMinhas: Have you tried `0`? Maybe that parameter doesn't matter for cursors. It says "If the parameter does not have a user-named or REF type, the typeName parameter is ignored." As explained in the edited answer, you're not calling any method like `getXXX()` where XXX is a type. Instead, you're calling `getResultSet()`.

Comment: Based off of https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/namespacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1sdbc_1_1DataType.html<br/> here is what i tried:<br/>Here is what i tried:  stmt  = oraCon.prepareCall("DECLARE V_Sqlstatement Varchar2(20); x sys_refcursor; BEGIN V_Sqlstatement:= 'SELECT * FROM DUAL'; OPEN x for v_Sqlstatement; ?:=x; End;")
 stmt.registerOutParameter(1, 1111, 0)
 rs=stmt.executeQuery()<br/> still no success

Comment: @ZTMinhas: The docs and the example use `execute()` for stored procedures, not `executeQuery()`. Also, try a simpler call first. Have you gotten rodolfo's example to work?

Comment: Here is how I implemented Rudolfo's work: ` openOracle("TEST_ORA") 
 stmt  = oraCon.prepareCall("DECLARE V_Sqlstatement Varchar2(20); BEGIN V_Sqlstatement:= 'THIS IS MY STRING';  ?:=V_Sqlstatement; End;")
 stmt.registerOutParameter(1, com.sun.star.sdbc.DataType.VARCHAR, "ignored")
 stmt.execute()
 print stmt.getString(1)`  And this works.

Comment: just to experiment, i made a bit further modification: ` openOracle("EPAT") 
 stmt  = oraCon.prepareCall("declare id number; begin insert into TABLE1(NAME1) values (?)  returning id1 into ?;  end;")
 stmt.setString(1, "FREDO")
 stmt.registerOutParameter(2, com.sun.star.sdbc.DataType.INTEGER, 0)
 stmt.execute()
 print stmt.getInt(2)` and this also works. I might need to modify my code in order to adjust for this, but I was hoping to return a result set.